# Error on creating simple map sample from google

Tags: dictionary, demo

I am trying to get the sample code from google work. I am geting this:

05-30 07:28:53.617: E/Trace(1361): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.harta/com.example.harta.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.example.harta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 11 more
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 20 more
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /data/app/com.example.harta-1.apk
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
05-30 07:28:54.197: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 23 more

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.harta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

This is example from Googl. Why isn't this sample code working?

Answer (score 0):

Try with "FragmentActivity" instead of "Activity". I had the same error.
here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
}}
```